# Shift centered site layout to one side according to rule (using css)

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a fixed size layout, centered using `margin: 0 auto`. I wonder whether it is possible to do such a thing with CSS: i need my layout to have right margin two times less then left. Something like:

```
<-- (2*n px margin) [fixed width div] (n px margin) -->
```

How? (using css only)

Comment: Why there will be scroll? I don't need a scroll, I just want that `left margin = 2 * right margin` and not `left margin = right margin` which I have in case `margin: 0 auto`. And this is top level container. So it have no wrapper with known fixed size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said CSS only, but I'd suggest using javascript in the following way:

```
function repad()
        {
            if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
            {
                var pad = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth-*FIXEDDIVWIDTH*)/3);
            }
            else
            {
                var pad = ((window.innerWidth-*FIXEDDIVWIDTH*)/3);
            }

            document.getElementById("*FIXEDDIV*").style.marginLeft = ((pad*2)+"px");
        }
```

Obviously replacing things in *'s with their proper values.

This way it's scalable to the browser size

Comment: There is probably a reason why the OP can't use JS.

Comment: as no more sufficient answers has been given, and nothing I have found by myself, I conclude that CSS realisation of my task is impossible or tricky. So, despite of JS used this is the only answer that reaches the goal.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can write like this:

```
<div class="warpper">
 <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.warpper{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:500px;
}
.container{
  width:450px;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/EVBc3/

Comment: It's top level container. Actually I did `margin:0 auto` on body tag :) Width of body is fixed, but width of window is somewhat unknown. And your example have only left margin, where is the right that twice as little as left? :)

Comment: First thing it's wrong to define width to a body tag & in the example #container is that div which you want to move shift. So, you can move the #container div according to your requirements.

Comment: I don't know the width of a wrapper. I don't know how much I should move container. I just know container's width and left-margin = 2 * right-margin. These are preconditions.